# Magnetic field generated by an electron in an electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

While studying the corrections of fine structure in the hydrogen atom my book tries to justify the spin-orbit term with some arguments about magnetic energy an spin. I'm fine with the calculations but I don't understand where his starting point comes from. It says that the magnetic field generated by an electron
moving in an eletric field $\vec{E}$ with velocity $\vec{v}$ is $$\vec{B}=-\frac{1}{c^2}\vec{E}\times\vec{v}$$
I've studied electromagnetism and a bit of special relativity, but I don't understand where this formula comes from.

Comment: This is worked out in some detail in the Feynman Lectures, in [Chapter 26](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_26.html), admittedly in units where $c=1$ ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would show it very briefly using Special Relativity:

Let's consider two frames $S$ and $S'$, with $S'$ moving with respect to $S$ at a velocity $v$. There is an electric field $\mathbf{E}$ in $S$, and the charge is at *rest* in $S'$. According to an observer in $S$, therefore, we have a charge moving in the electric field $\mathbf{E}$.

Now let's look at it from the charge's point of view: the charge only sees a static electric field in the universe, and describes it using a scalar potential. The four-potential the charge sees is therefore:

$$A'^\mu = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\phi'}{c}\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

(note that primed quantities represent quantities measured in the $S'$ frame). How can we relate this to the four-potential in the $S$ (or "lab") frame? Well, using a Lorentz Transformation it's easy to see that (if the $S'$ is moving along the positive $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ direction),

$$A^\mu = \begin{pmatrix}\gamma \frac{\phi'}{c}\\\gamma \frac{v}{c^2}\phi'\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},$$

which means that the new electric and magnetic potentials are
\begin{aligned}\phi &= \gamma \phi'\\ A_x &= \frac{v}{c^2}\gamma\phi',\end{aligned}

and substituting for $\phi'$, you can show that $$A_x = \frac{v}{c^2}\phi.$$

Of course, what we have done so far assumes the velocity to be only along $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$ which is just to simplify our work. It's possible (but for more tedious) to show that for an arbitrary velocity $\mathbf{v}$,

$$\mathbf{A} = \frac{\mathbf{v}}{c^2} \phi.$$

From here, it's a very short step to calculate the magnetic field, since

$$\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{\nabla \times A} = \frac{1}{c^2}\mathbf{\nabla \times }(\mathbf{v}\phi).$$

Since $\mathbf{v}$ is a constant, we can use a standard relation from vector calculus, that for a scalar function $\psi$ and a constant vector $\mathbf{C}$:

$$\mathbf{\nabla \times}(\psi \mathbf{C}) = \psi (\mathbf{\nabla \times C}) + (\nabla\psi)\times\mathbf{C}.$$

Using this relation, it can be shown very simply (since $\mathbf{v}$ is constant) that

$$\mathbf{B} = \frac{1}{c^2} (\nabla \phi) \times \mathbf{v},$$

and the definition of the electric field tells us that $$\mathbf{E} = - \nabla\phi,$$

and so $$\mathbf{B} = -\frac{1}{c^2} \left(\mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{v}\right)$$

Comment: So this is only true if E is the eectric field generated by the point charge itself? I thought that the formula referred to an electrostatic field in S generated by something else. But if this was the case than in S' we wouldn't have just an electrostatic field in S', right?

Comment: No, I think this is a more general relation. Remember that nowhere have I used the actual *form* of $\phi$. If in the frame $S'$ there exists only an electrostatic field, then in $S$ a magnetic field will be observed, which is $\mathbf{v\times E}$. The field is $S'$ may be due to a single point charge, or due to some other configuration.